# Is there a reason not to default to using fragments in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, code-formatting

The standard way to write a functional component in React.js is to use a `return ( ... )` statement. React needs the return of a functional component to be a single node, though, so often fragments are written to wrap all the contents like `return (<> ... </>)`.

Is there a reason beyond aesthetics people don't write `return <> ... </>` by default? It seems like an intuitive component structure that eliminates the single node error. I've never seen a component written this way a single time.

Example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   // Logic
   return <>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <button>Click Me</button>
   </>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by default? If there is a single child, it turns out to be **unnecessary**.
Prettier would break your code into multiple lines.

Its

```
return <div />;
```

vs

```
return (
   <>
      <div />
   </>
);
```

If you get used to using unnecessary fragments, your code will turn out to be much longer than it needs to be.